# Ignore attr_accessible under Rails 4 strong parameters transition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app and I currently use the `protected_attributes` gem. It works fine but now I feel I need to transition to strong parameters.
So the thing is I don't want to remove "attr_accessible" before all my tests pass.
I tried to remove the "protected_attributes" in my gemfile and then I got this error:
"`attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one."
I want to just ignore this error until all my tests pass how should I do that?

Comment: comment out the calls to `attr_accessible`? :)

Comment: Comment out attr_accessible is good! I was thinking a less destructive way of doing things. Im thinking how far will I go in my test go? Currently it doesn't show the amount of tests failing just quits directly before the tests start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sevenseacat points out, you should comment out all attr_accessible calls in all your classes. Yes, or your tests will break now, but that is actually a good thing. If all your tests were green and turn red now, you know exactly on which controllers you should add strong parameters. Seems to me the whole point of the red -> green cycle.

So please, let your tests fail and use the commented out attr_accessible calls as a reference for which attributes to require and permit in the corresponding controllers. As long as you don't make other changes you should not worry about breaking your test suite. You know what needs to be done to fix it.

Comment: The problem is that when I run the tests it quits directly with the error message. So I cannot even start the testsuit.

Comment: You can after commenting out all attr_accessible calls though. After you''ve done that you are ready for refactoring.